# gawk - Extracting Text and putting it on the same line

Tags: regex, parsing, awk, gawk

Okay, I have some text:

```
=== Blah 1 ===
::Junk I wish: 2 Ignore <br/>
::More Junk: 1.2-2.7 <br/>
::ABC: [http://www.google.com (STUFF/I/Want)]<br/>
::More2: Ignore<br/>
::More Stuf 2 Ignore: N/A<br/>

=== Blah 2 ===
::Junk I wish: More 2 Ignore <br/>
::More Junk: 1.2-2.7 <br/>
::ABC: [http://www.google.com (Other/STUFF/I/Want)]<br/>
::More2: More Ignore<br/>
::More Stuf 2 Ignore: More N/A<br/>
```

I want to output:

```
Blah 1, (STUFF/I/Want)
Blah 2, (Other/STUFF/I/Want)
```

I've figured out how to grab portions of the lines I want:

```
gawk  '/===/ {print } /ABC/ {print $3}' file_name
```

This outputs the following:

```
=== Blah 1 ===
(STUFF/I/Want)]<br/>
=== Blah 2 ===
(Other/STUFF/I/Want)]<br/>
```

What I don't understand is how to strip out the other characters I don't want, and put this on one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way.

Content of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    ## Characters to separate output fields
    OFS = ", "
}

## When line begins with several equal signs, remove them, both leading
## and trailing, and save the title.
$1 ~ /^=+$/ {
    gsub( /\s*=\s*/, "", $0 )
    title = $0
    next
}

## For the second field, split line with both pair of parentheses and 
## print second field.
$1 ~ /ABC/ {

    ## For GNU-Awk
    #split( $0, abc_line, /(\()|(\))/, seps )
    #printf "%s%s%s%s%s\n", title, OFS, seps[1], abc_line[2], seps[2]

    ## For Awk
    split( $0, abc_line, /(\()|(\))/ )
    printf "%s%s(%s)\n", title, OFS, abc_line[2]

}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

And it yields:

```
Blah 1, (STUFF/I/Want)
Blah 2, (Other/STUFF/I/Want)
```

Comment: Thank-you for the clear explanation on your code, verses just giving me an answer. I am looking to learn here, so this is greatly appreciated.

Do you have any idea why I'm being told that split only takes 3 arguments?

Comment: Why not just `title = $2" "$3`?

Comment: @Doug: I'm afraid that the 4-argument `split` function is from the `GNU awk`. I've edited the script to work with normal `awk` too.

Comment: @sudo_O: Just in case the title is longer than 2 words.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using Gnu Awk, but a port taken to Windows. Perhaps its behind a few versions then. The modified code runs great. Thank-you!

Comment: BTW, good point on the 2-words. In my actual data its often more than two words. As a result this solution works, while the other did not. I just changed the accepted answer.

Comment: Good point @Doug I modified my answer to meet this requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Use `printf` instead of `print` to omit the newline character and only print the second and third fields in the first block and use `sub` to throw away the stuff you don't want in the second block:

```
awk '/===/{printf "%s %s, ",$2,$3}/ABC/{sub(/].*/,"");print $3}' file
Blah 1, (STUFF/I/Want)
Blah 2, (Other/STUFF/I/Want)
```

If title is variable length:

```
awk '/===/{gsub(/ ?=+ ?/,"");printf "%s, ",$0}/ABC/{sub(/].*/,"");print $3}' file
Blah 1, (STUFF/I/Want)
Blah 2, (Other/STUFF/I/Want)
```

Comment: Thank-you, this did exactly what I was looking for and its very concise.

Comment: No problem, you was very close. Keep at it `awk` is very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk '/===/{header=gensub(" *=== *","","g",$0)} /ABC/{abc=gensub("]<br/>","","g",$3); print header", "abc}' file_name
```

This might work for you. It saves the stripped info into variables, then prints them.

Comment: Why not just `/===/{header=$2" "$3}` for the first block and you miss the `]` in the second `gensub("]<br/>","","g",$3)`

Comment: Well I typed it in under 1 minute, didn't think too much. Your solution is right too.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in awk, if you look for an unorthodox **record** separator, the solution becomes pretty simple:

```
awk -v RS=' *=== *|[()]' '
  NR%4==2 {printf "%s, ", $0}
  NR%4==0 {print "(" $0 ")"}
'
```

Here, a record separator is `===` optionally surrounded by spaces, or a left or right parenthesis.